# Erro de argumentos no Unity Photon

Tags: c#, unity3d, script

Estava desenvolvendo um projeto online e eu citei a seguinte função -
`PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom`, e ocorreu-me o seguinte erro:

> Assets/Scripts/Sindico.cs(53,31): error CS1501: No overload for method `CreateRoom` takes `0` arguments

Está pedindo 4 argumentos:

- 1° Argumento - `string roomName`
- 2° Argumento - `RoomOptions roomOptions`
- 3° Argumento - `TypeLobby typeLobby`
- 4° Argumento - `Ainda nao sei!`

Como solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Mostre seu código do `CreateRoom`, é só [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar isso. Olhando [este artigo](https://doc.photonengine.com/en/realtime/current/reference/matchmaking-and-lobby) vejo que a função leva 3 argumentos (mas C# não é minha praia...)

Comment: vou ver se funciona

Answer (score 0):

Faz tempo desde que você fez a pergunta, mas caso alguém ainda tenha essa dúvida, pode consultar a resposta.

Primeiramente, você tem que ter em mente que para criar uma sala no Photon você precisa estar conectado no Lobby. Caso isso tenha sido feito, você precisará então rodar o método PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom().

O erro que você recebe é porque o método não tem um construtor que aceite sua instanciação sem método. E na verdade, ele não precisa de 4 argumentos, **você pode criar com apenas um: o nome da sala**

Ex: PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("minha_sala");

Lembrando que ele conecta automaticamente à sala quando você à cria. Para saber se tudo rolou bem, você pode usar esse método:

```
void OnJoinedRoom(){
    Debug.Log("Entrei na sala com sucesso!");
}
```

Se você ainda tiver com dúvidas, dá uma olhada nesse vídeo que cobre toda a parte de lobby:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJg24zvd_8o

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.